# XKB_DEFAULT_OPTIONS=grp:shift_caps_switch with more than two keyboard layouts

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, user-input, keyboard-layout

This option if set allows me to switch to first (us) and second (ru) layouts by simply pressing CapsLock and Shift+CapsLock respectively.
I'm happy with that behavior, since it's very ergonomic and distraction-free.

However, additionally I need third (pl) and fourth (ua) layouts, and looks like there's no predefined shortcut for them, nor any (documented?) option to enable it.

I don't want to change CapsLock → us, Shift+CapsLock → ru, behavior, ideally Ctrl+CapsLock shortcut should cycle between secondary (pl and ua) layouts.
What's the best way to bind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've switched to sway WM and got a proper setup with the following config:

```
input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" {
    xkb_options caps:none,shift:both_capslock,compose:ralt
    xkb_layout us
    xkb_numlock enabled
}

bindcode Ctrl+Shift+66 \
    input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" xkb_layout ua; \
    input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" xkb_options caps:none,shift:both_capslock,compose:ralt

bindcode      Shift+66 \
    input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" xkb_layout ru; \
    input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" xkb_options caps:none,shift:both_capslock,compose:ralt

bindcode       Ctrl+66 \
    input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" xkb_layout pl; \
    input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" xkb_options caps:none,shift:both_capslock,lv3:ralt_switch_multikey

bindcode            66 \
    input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" xkb_layout us; \
    input "1:1:AT_Translated_Set_2_keyboard" xkb_options caps:none,shift:both_capslock,compose:ralt
```

Here, I've disabled primary CapsLock, so it started to emit 66 keycode which then I've bound to combinations with other keys to corresponding keyboard layouts.

Also, `xkb_options` are set alongside just to bind `RightAlt` as `compose` key on `ua`, `ru`, `us` and as `lv3` symbols access key on `pl` layout.

CapsLock functionality is still accessible with `shift:both_capslock` option.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `toggle` option.

```
XKB_DEFAULT_OPTIONS=grp:shift_caps_toggle
```

You could also pass this to the `setxkb` command

```
setxkbmap -rules xorg -model $model -layout "us,ru,pl,ua" \
 -option "grp:shift_caps_toggle"
```

The documentation is rather spotty but you could use [the xorg documentation](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/input/XKB-Config.html) or [source description](https://xkbcommon.org/).

Admittedly as mentioned in the comments this is less than ideal, however setting two keygroups should be trivial.

```
# This is the primary set
setxkbmap -rules xorg -model $model -layout "us,ru" \
 -option "grp:shift_caps_toggle"
# This is the secondary 
setxkbmap -rules xorg -model $model -layout "pl,ua" \
 -option "grp:ctrl_caps_toggle"
```

Comment: Not what I want, since then I will must look at layout indicator, and press 4 times (in worst case) to find proper layout, which is very unergonomic

Comment: Perhaps setting 2 key combinations would work? One for switching between primary and secondary and one for the other two? I have modified my answer.